# Selenium Exception Handling Design

Tags: java, selenium, design-patterns, exception

In Order to prevent exception handling in each method in selenium page objects, i thought to have a general exception handling, a try catch in the test block,
other handlers only if more specific handling required,

Now the issue is that this process needs to be written in each test...
is there a way to make the test methods have this common test handling written once for all tests?

```
@Test
public void test(WebDriver driver) {        
    try {
        // common code in the try block
        // using testNG may be moved to @BeforeMethod And @AfterMethod
        Logger.log("Test Started....");

        Logger.log("Test Ended....");
        Assert.assertAll();
    }
    catch() {
        // in Case Automation Fails, common operations required 
        ScreenShoot.getScreenShoot(); 
    }
    finally 
    {   
        // finally for all tests    
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jUnit, you can create a TestWatcher Rule (the TestNG alternative `ITestListener` is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28864599/5127499)).

```
public class YourTestWatcherImplementation extends TestWatcher() {
    @Override
    protected void starting(Description description) {
        // initialize your WebDriver
        // perhaps login to your tested application?
    }

    @Override
    protected void finished(Description description) {
        // shutdown your WebDriver
    }

    @Override
    protected void failed(Throwable error,
            Description description) {
        // take a screenshot
        // do more error handling/reporting
    }
}
```

This way, your tests only contain the actual test code and you got all the preparation/tearDown in one place.
Each test class only needs a public member variable with the `@Rule` annotation like this:

```
public class OneOfYourTestClasses {
    @Rule
    public TestWatcher watcher = new YourTestWatcherImplementation();

    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
        ...
    }

    @Test
    public void testEvenMore() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: do this solution also handles exceptions and print stack traces exactly like the try catch in example code?

Comment: In case of an Exception, the TestWatcher.failed() method is invoked an the catched error is given as the first parameter. With this Throwable you can do as you please - print the stack trace, log it, or ignore it - since jUnit already registered the error and marks the test run as failure.

Comment: This demo is exactly what i searched for but it appears to work only with Junit, testNG have a different approach not using @Rule in BaseTest class, it uses a listener in the added to the suite, so the listener will only work if i run the suite not the test class.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to create parent test class, which all other tests will extend. In this parent test class, create @AfterMethod, which will take screenshot on failure. Here is an example (although without inheritance):

http://artoftesting.com/automationTesting/screenShotInSelenium.html